# Tool to convert SWF files to PDF

Tags: pdf, flash, converters

Is there any open source tool to convert SWF to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a tool called [SWF Printer Pro](http://download.cnet.com/SWF-Printer-Pro/3000-10743_4-10740922.html) and resolve all my needs.

Comment: That's for printing to swf, not to convert swf to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [eConverter](https://bitbucket.org/esminis/econverter) tool. I found some problems with convertion pixel images in .swf, but vector shapes (text) had perfect ouput.